# How do I synchronize AoG releases to versions of my Fulfillment on Firebase Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

It seems to me that Actions on Google's release model is a poor match for how Firebase Functions are released. In AoG, I can snapshot "versions" of my Dialogflow implementation and deploy them to Alpha, Beta, and Release at my leisure. Those snapshots include the URL of my Fulfillment. Assuming I want the behavior of my Action to remain consistent through Alpha, Beta, and Release, I need to keep the Fulfillment the same for the entire lifetime of the snapshot. This seems to me to mean that I need a separate deployment of my Fulfillment for each release (not each environment, because releases move through environments).

With Firebase Functions, the name of my function is hard-coded into my JavaScript file as a module export. Every time I deploy, the previous deployment is overwritten. I started going down the path of maintaining multiple Projects, but I'd have to create a new project for every release, and sharing data (in Firestore) across them becomes a hassle. I tried sticking a release number in the name of the function, but the other thing Firebase Functions does is delete any old functions that are deployed but now missing from my source. That means I can't just leave a bunch of versions running without seriously gumming up my source code / CI.

App Engine has a first-class concept of "versions" where every deployment gets its own URL. This maps beautifully to AoG's snapshots: for development I can point my Fulfillment Webhook URL at the base URL of my Fulfillment (e.g. https://my-fulfillment.appspot.com/), and then when I'm ready to release I lock it to an App Engine version (e.g. https://20180708t215225-dot-my-fulfillment.appspot.com/). I can leave this version deployed indefinitely and deploy new versions without affecting the behavior of my now-locked snapshot. It seems like the App Engine model here lines up perfectly with AoG, while Firebase Functions doesn't.

How do I manage versions of my Firebase Function serving as a Fulfillment to an Action on Google such that a given AoG Release always gets the same Fulfillment implementation?

Comment: were you able to find any elegant solution for this?

Comment: Yeah: use Google App Engine's Standard Node.js environment. GAE supports versions really well.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't direct versioning for Firebase Cloud Functions yet, but what you could do to avoid having different projects is to export the cloud functions with the versioning in their name, so that you would even have separate logs for each release (alpha, beta or production).

```
exports.myCloudFunction_V1 = functions.https.onRequest(app)
exports.myCloudFunction_V2 = functions.https.onRequest(app)
exports.myCloudFunction_V3 = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

or

```
exports.myCloudFunction_aplha = functions.https.onRequest(app)
exports.myCloudFunction_beta = functions.https.onRequest(app)
exports.myCloudFunction_prod = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Just remember to work on your project separated by branches for each version, and when you want a deployment between them you only need to send a PR from one branch to another.

Git will give you the ability to change the code structure between versions.